# Field not searchable in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index myindex in elasticsearch, loaded a few documents into it. When I visit:

```
localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/1023
```

I noticed that my particular index has the following metadata for mappings:

```
mappings: {
  mappinggroupname: {
    properties: {
      Aproperty: {
        type: string
      }
      Bproperty: {
        type: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there some way to add "store:yes" and index: "analyzed" without having to reload/reindex all the documents?

Note that when i want to view a single document...

i.e. localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/1023

I can see the _source field contains all the fields of that document are and when I go to the "Browser" section of the head plugin it appears that all the columns are correct and corresponding to my fieldnames. So why is it that "stored" is not showing up in metadata? I can even perform a _search on them.

What is the difference between "stored":"true" versus the fact that I can see all my fields and values after indexing all my documents via the means I mention above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, no way! That's how your documents got indexed in the underlying lucene. The only way to change it is to reindex them all!

You see all those fields because you see the content of the special [`_source`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field/) field in lucene, that's stored by default through elasticsearch. You are not storing all the fields separately but you do have the source document that you originally indexed through the `_source`, a single field that contains the whole document.

Generally the `_source` field is just enough, you don't usually need to configure every field as stored.

Also, the default is `"index":"analyzed"` if not specified for all the `string` fields. That means those fields are indexed and analyzed using the standard analyzer if not specified in the mapping. Therefore, as far as I can see from your mapping those two fields should be indexed, thus searchable.

Comment: But I can see all the fields when I go into my _head application's "Browser" and the source document does contain all the fields. Shoudnt they already be technically "stored"?